# What could be wrong with this SQL query?

Tags: sql

The (very) simple query does not work. I can't figure out what is wrong.

The problem occurs with 1 particular row in the Table : when Ticker = "ATR"

Here is a part of the table containing the data that I am querying:

[image]

Ticker = "ATR" does exist.
A column filter in the DB Viewer UI works as expected.
[image]

So we are actualy certain that Ticker="ATR"
DOES REALLY exist.

BUT the simple query does not yield anything...

```
SELECT * FROM ticker_series_table WHERE Ticker ="ATR";
```

[image]

This 'kinda' works, except for Ticker="ATR"
[image]

Can somebody explain what could be going on please?
I cant figure out what is happening...

Comment: please don't post images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: use TRIM(ticker)

Comment: Check if there are spaces you don't see, try something like `SELECT * FROM ticker_series_table WHERE UPPER(Ticker) LIKE '%ATR%'`

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ANSI SQL has single quotes for string literals, and double quotes for delimited identifiers.

Comment: It's likely there's a non-display value in with ATR causing the issue such as a space, tab, hard return, carrige return line feed, etc...  you may have to get the ascii values to know which or guess and check..

Comment: Thanks everyone,
UPPER(Ticker) = 'ATR' 

did it!

Comment: Correction!

The problem was the double quotes!  <">should be single quotes <'>

DOES NOT WORK:
SELECT * FROM ticker_series_table WHERE Ticker ="ATR"; 

WORKS:
SELECT * FROM ticker_series_table WHERE Ticker ='ATR';


That's odd... I wasn't aware of this..